# ELB information in the chef server

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe, amazon-elb

I am bootstrapping EC2 ubuntu instances using chef-provisioning. I can create multiple machines and create a new ELB and attach the machines to the ELB. But I am looking for ELB's information at chef server. I am using open source chef server, not the hosted chef server.

Is it possible to populate the ELB's information on Chef-server, I have to use the A record of the ELB in the templates.

```
require 'chef/provisioning/aws_driver'
with_driver 'aws::ap-southeast-1'

ruby_block 'get_elb' do
  block do
    load_balancer "test-elb" do
        machines [ "machine1", "machine2" ]
            load_balancer_options({
               :availability_zones => "ap-southeast-1a",
               listeners: [
            {
                instance_port: 80,
                protocol: 'HTTP',
                instance_protocol: 'HTTP',
                port: 80
            }   
               ]
            })  

    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`aws_object` accessor](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-aws#aws_object) to get the underlying ELB data in a `ruby_block` and write it into the provisioner node's attributes (or maybe store it in a data bag, but that is a gross and brittle solution so tread lightly).

Comment: How do I add the cluster / machine definition inside a ruby_block ? Do let me know.

Comment: You don't, you do that outside like in the example I linked. Then you put the resource object in a variable (again, like in the example) and use it later on inside a `ruby_block`.

Comment: I got it working and also saving the information at chef server too. Thank you